# Example of group $G$ such that $Z(G)$ has no elements of order $2$, $Z(G) \neq G$ and $Z(G)$ is non-trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The title of the question explains it all. I was looking for information about centers of groups and realized that I couldn't find any examples of non-abelian groups such that their centers were nontrivial and did not contain any element of order $2$.

All I could find was that if $G$ contained an unique element of order $2$, then $Z(G)$ must contain it.

Also, what happens if, in addition to all these conditions, we impose that $G$ needs to have elements of order $2$? Do we continue having examples? Do we continue not having examples? Did we have examples before but with this new condition we don't?

Comment: For example, take the Heisenberg group over $\Bbb F_3$ with $27$ elements. Its center is non-trivial and proper and has no elements of order $2$ by Lagrange.

Comment: Even simpler, $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: The reason why a unique element of order $2$ must be central is that the conjugate of $x$ has the same order as $x$, so if $x$ is the only element of order $k$, then $gxg^{-1}=x$ for all $g$. However, "is the only element of order $k$" can only happen when $k=1$ or when $k=2$, since for $k\gt 2$, if $x$ has order $k$ then so does $x^{-1}$, and $x^{-1}\neq x$, so the argument no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

Any nontrivial $p$-group has non trivial center. If $p>2$ then clearly such a group will not have any elements of order $2$. So you have just have to find such a group which is not abelian. Here is one such group:

$G=\{\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\;|\; a,b,c\in \Bbb{F}_3\}$

Answer (score 2):

For finite groups the generalization you were looking for runs as follows.

**Proposition** Let $N \unlhd G$ with $|N|=p$, the *smallest* prime dividing the order of $G$. Then $N \subseteq Z(G)$.

**Proof** We use the $N/C$-theorem (for a subgroup $H$ of $G$, the $N/C$ theorem states that the factor group $N_G(H)/C_G(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of Aut$(H)$, the group of automorphisms of $H$). One can also prove it by using the class equation. Anyway, the normality of $N$ implies $G=N_G(N)$, and it follows that $G/C_G(N)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $C_{p-1}$. But $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, hence $G/C_G(N)$ must be trivial, that is, $G=C_G(N)$, equivalent to $N$ being central. $\square$